# How to properly catch and nest ValidationErrors

Tags: django

I would like to nest validation errors in order to allow the exact causes of an error to be pinpointed, but it appears that Django's ValidationError does not allow nesting of nested errors.

Here is a toy example:

```
def not_nested():
        raise ValidationError(_('invalid'))

def nested():
    errors = dict()
    for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        try:
            not_nested()
        except ValidationError as e:
            errors[x] = e
    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)

def nested_again():
    errors = dict()
    for x in ['1', '2', '3']:
        try:
            nested()
        except ValidationError as e:
            errors[x] = e
    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)
```

Single nesting works fine:

```
nested()
# raises:
ValidationError: {'a': ['invalid'], 'b': ['invalid'], 'c': ['invalid']}
```

But nesting twice does not:

```
nested_again()
# raises
AttributeError: 'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'error_list'
```

Is this intended or a bug? Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `error_dict` from `ValidationError` object

```
def nested_again():
    errors = dict()
    for x in ['1', '2', '3']:
        try:
            nested()
        except ValidationError as e:
            errors[x] = e.error_dict  # Here
    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)
```